# How to create keyless URL parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519540/618206) describing ASP.NET support for keyless (not valueless) parameters, like `http://some.url?param1&param2`, and confirmed them to be viewable on `Request.QueryString` like:

```
var values = this.Request.QueryString.GetValues(null);
values.Any(o => o == "param1");
```

This is fine and dandy but now I want to generate urls like this. My first intuition was to use the `RouteValueDictionary: routeValues` parameter of  `Url.Action` with null as a key:

```
@{ 
    var dict = new RouteValueDictionary();
    dict.Add(null, "param1");
    dict.Add(null, "param2");
}
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", dict)">Very link, amaze</a>
```

But apparently C# [forbids nulls as dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174715/618206) because of reasons.

I have also tried the empty string as the key, but it results in a query string like: `?=param1,=param2` which contains 2 more equal signs that I want it to.

Of course I can string manipulate the heck out of my URL and add the `&param1` part to the query string, but I was hoping for a concise solution.

Comment: Why not to use routing? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: @2316116 could you actually elaborate on how to "use routing" to create URLs I described?

Comment: Routing is typically using / as a separator between keys and values and url looks as http://server/url/param1/param2 - so if using ? and & is not a must - use routing.

Comment: @2316116 I see what you mean. Would be a good alternative, thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no built-in helper for this why don't you roll your own:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string MyAction(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string actionName, IList<string> parameters)
    {
        string url = urlHelper.Action(actionName);
        if (parameters == null || !parameters.Any())
        {
            return url;
        }

        return string.Format("{0}?{1}", url, string.Join("&", parameters));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@{
    var parameters = new List<string>();
    parameters.Add("param1");
    parameters.Add("param2");
}

@Url.MyAction("ActionName", parameters)
```

Comment: I rolled one with support for mixing keyless and key/value parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the key values, but leaving the value null isn't allowed.

[RouteValueDictionary ignores empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009162/routevaluedictionary-ignores-empty-values)

You could add a value like 1 for instance, but you lose your fine and dandy solution.

```
    @{
        var dict = new RouteValueDictionary();
        dict.Add("param1",1);
    }
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", dict)">Very link, amaze</a>
```

For another solution you will have to write some custom code.

Comment: Could you clarify? If you specify `"param1"` key and null or string.Empty value the Url.Action helper will not include this parameter in the generated url. Or maybe I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: I thought it would work but i edited my answer cause empty values are indeed ignored.

Comment: Sadly including placeholder values like 1 is precisely what I don't want to do, that is precisely why I asked the question.